# missing in props validation react/prop-types

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The solutions provided when doing my research are based on React class and not React function and I'm just a newbie in React.

From the parent component I'm calling the child component and passing the values as 'data'. In the child component I'm retrieving the value using props.

***ParentComponent.js***

```
<ChildComponent data={1}/>
```

***ChildComponent.js***

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
    const { data } = props.data;
    ...
}
```

The above gives me the following error message:

> src\components\ChildComponent\ChildComponent.js   Line 5:11:
> 'data.data' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types   Line
> 5:29:  'data' is missing in props validation          react/prop-types
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: `const { data } = props.data` is the equivalent of doing: `const dataVariable = props.data.data`. Perhaps remove `.data`. Therefore, updating the code to be `const {data} = props`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Denno and @Nick Vu is correct but there might be something else you'll have to add to your child component just before the export.

```
ChildComponent.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object
};
```

and add import

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
```

and change this

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
    const { data } = props.data;
    ...
}
```

to

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
    const data = props.data;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why adding the propTypes help? I can understand that it is a sort of annotation to React (correct me if I'm wrong - it is a guess). I'm mainly asking this because I'm not sure I like to import a new dependency to the project just for the sake of annotation. If no imports were needed, I would have been at ease...

Answer (score 5):

`props` is collecting all attributes which you pass to `ChildComponent`

Your data should be like this

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
    const { data } = props; //object destructuring
    ...
}
```

Or like this

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
    const data = props.data //access data directly and assign a new variable
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should learn something about ES6（Destructuring Assignment）, if you want to konw this meaning about  `const { data } = props.data`

or simple chang code to this

```
function ChildComponent(props) {
    const data = props.data 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I add missing `import * as React from 'react';` resolved this